# More natural responses from Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-lex

I'm creating a chatbot using Amazon Lex. I'm collecting information from the user, but I'd like to have some more natural sounding responses. As an example, the bot asks "what's the last sport you participated in", expecting something like "football", "baseball" etc back from the user. Our response to that right now is "Great, I love {sport}!". However this has obvious problems with users making the bot say funny/rude things, and in general just doesn't feel natural because it feels like text replacement (because it is).

Instead I'd like to have something more natural feeling depending on what sport the user enters. For example if you say "football" it might say "I like to toss around the pigskin myself." (I'm a programmer, not an author).

I've tried doing this with conditionals, but it doesn't seem very scalable beyond a few sports. It involves the bot "understanding" what sport the user is asking about, which I don't see an easy way to do using the conditional syntax. Is this something that would have to be handled with Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. The full capabilities of any Lex bot can only be unleashed once you pair it with a Lambda function.

Your Lambda functional should ideally handle input validation to cater for wisecrack responses. You can also implement custom logic within your Lambda to respond with a sport-specific quip as and when necessary.